# Como trabajar en dos tablas al mismo tiempo en MySql

Tags: mysql

requiero poder generar un reporte con la cantidad de producto vendida por categoría y ordenarlo por código de categoría

Estoy trabajando con las tablas customers y products de la base de datos **Northwind en MySql**

Solicito ayuda para poder entender como puede armar un query, usando las dos tablas (customers y products)

La sintaxis que estoy trabajando en la siguiente:
SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName
from Categories

Este sería el resultado que necesito listar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Contenido de la tabla Categories:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

products

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitamos las columnas que ocupan las 2 tablas, así como datos importantes si por ejemplo están vinculadas por su id o no por favor

Comment: has un `DESCRIBE tablaNombre` a cada una y lo que te devuelva agrégalo a la pregunta

Comment: Listo, las coloque en la formulación de la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor no uses imágenes a menos que sea estrictamente necesario con un `DESCRIBE` agrega en formato de texto los nombres de las columnas por favor a parte de lo que hayas tratado, te recomiendo leer sobre [joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: De acuerdo gracias por la acotación.

Comment: tengo una copia de esa base de datos, pero no me queda claro ¿en la tabla productos que columna es la que almacena la cantidad vendida de cada producto?

Comment: creo que podría ser de la tabla producto que tiene una columna llamada CategoryID (que se cotejaria con la tabla de categories) y se tomaría la columna QuantityPerUnit de la tabla products para llegar la cantidad vendida de productos.

Comment: Quedo super atento y gracias por ayuda.

Comment: La tabla `products`  es el maestro de productos, las ventas si no me equivoco se manejan en otras tablas `Orders` y  `OrdersDetails`.

Comment: Hola Patricio gracias por la atención, si las ventas técnicamente estarían en la tabla products lo estoy mirando que podría ser QuantityPerUnit (que tiene las cantidades por el precio UnitPrice Que me recomiendas?? no e podido lograr listar el reporte  de este forma debería arrojar los registros:                 .categoryID CategoryName Productos Vendidos                                        
          1          Beverages             9532                                                              
          2          Condiments           5298

Comment: No @maikervasquez en la tabla productos se guarda los registros de los productos ingresados, si revisas lo que tu buscas es el resultado de una acción (las ventas), entonces lo que te dice Patricio es correcto, deberás revisar la estructura de las otras tablas para encontrar donde se guarda la cantidad vendida

Comment: Gracias estimados, sin embargo revise una a una de las tablas (13) en total y no encontre algun dato que me indicara las ventas por ello pienso que la tabla products que tiene el campo QuantityPerUnit se podría multiplicar por el  UnitPrice que opinan???